# Can Mac OS X El Capitan run software compiled for Yosemite that expects libraries in /usr/gnu64/lib?

Tags: c, macos, osx-elcapitan

<sup>*Sorry, there's a bit of background necessary — you could try skipping to the **Question** heading.*</sup>

Since time immemorial (somewhere in the previous millennium, anyway), I've created directories such as `/usr/gnu` and `/usr/gcc` to hold custom-compiled GNU software, separate from anything in the system directories.  This has worked well for me, on a wide variety of Unix-based systems, including Mac OS X since 2002 (Jaguar, 10.2).  (One reason for not using `/usr/local` was that the IT management maintained it, and it always contained archaic code — it had Perl 4 available until about 5 years ago, for example.  Using other names avoided run-ins with them.)

With Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan, Apple has introduced the SIP (System Integrity Protection) system (described at [What is the "rootless" feature of El Capitan, really?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) on 'Ask Different').  It means that I can no longer create directories such as `/usr/gnu` or `/usr/gcc`, even though they're disjoint from anything that Apple has.

I found that the software previously in those directories had been quarantined in directories like these (where the UUIDs will be different on your machine, and I probably have two because getting El Capitan onto this machine was a multi-step operation — a separate long and boring story):

```
$ ls -1 /Library/SystemMigration/History/
Migration-7D74B534-AA54-4A4A-8DCC-A5C2F28E1A39
Migration-9C0FE7A4-3445-4BD6-A512-35464EECCBC3
$
```

and then in sub-directories under `QuarantineRoot`:

```
$ ls /Library/SystemMigration/History/Migration-9C0FE7A4-3445-4BD6-A512-35464EECCBC3/QuarantineRoot/usr:
gcc      gnu32    gnu64
$
```

However, the binaries were compiled with GCC and various libraries, so they don't run at the moment.  For example:

```
$ otool -L bison
bison:
    /usr/gnu64/lib/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.1.0)
    /usr/gnu64/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 744.18.0)
    /usr/gcc/v4.7.1/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
$ ./bison
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/gnu64/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/SystemMigration/History/Migration-9C0FE7A4-3445-4BD6-A512-35464EECCBC3/QuarantineRoot/usr/gnu64/bin/./bison
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
$
```

AFAIK, I can't even create symlinks in `/usr` such that `gcc` or `gnu64` points somewhere else (not even running with root privileges).  That's one of the techniques I've used to create software on MachineA with spare space in `/work1` for use on another MachineB with spare space in `/work5`; a symlink in `/usr` allows the code to sit in `/work1/gcc` or `/work5/gcc` and it works correctly as long as `/usr/gcc` points to where the files are actually installed.  So, this SIP system seems to kill all the mechanisms used successfully for a couple of decades which are predicated on being able to create at least some sort of directory entry in `/usr`.

#### Question

- Is there a sensible way to get the old binaries to run *without* disabling SIP and without having to recompile everything immediately?

The fall-back position is "recompile the software — avoiding `/usr` as an install location".  Over time, I plan to use `/opt/gcc` and `/opt/gnu64` instead of the equivalents under `/usr`.  I'm even contemplating using space under my home directory, even though I'd rather not; it is 'system' software.

However, I have quite a lot of software already compiled, including multiple versions of GCC (from 4.4.2 through 5.2.0), which it will be a nuisance to recompile.  In fact, I'll have to abandon the old versions of GCC, which I don't use all that often, but which are useful when I do need them.

---

<sup>*Oh, and I've got a problem with the configure script for GNU Tar (1.28 and 1.26). It tests how deep a directory tree it can create, and then is unable to clean-up.  And neither `rm` nor `rmdir` can clean up either, even if I `cd` down the hierarchy to the bottom.  It gets an 'out of disk space' error, even though there's lots of space left. I can use Finder to move the hierarchy to Trash.  But Finder can't remove them either.  Bash has a tizzy because it can't work out what the current directory is.  It is all kinda painful!  So recompiling and reinstalling some of the software is not going to be trivial.  I may even end up using stuff compiled by other people (MacPorts, HomeBrew, etc), but I like to be able to compile my own.  I get the error 'The operation can’t be completed because the item “confdir-14B---” is in use'; a reboot may be in order, but I'm not confident it will fix that problem.*</sup>

Comment: One Tumbleweed badge later (which wasn't the intention at the outset), I'm ready to assume that the answer is "No, there isn't a way around the problem that is reasonably sane", so the complete set of rebuilds is in order.  The tar issue has been reported to the GNU tar maintainers; there's an action item response to me that I've not yet taken the necessary steps on.  (I don't believe this would have been on-topic at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) — I looked before asking here and it seemed to be explicitly excluded from their list of on-topic items.)

Comment: I just came across [this web page](http://digitizor.com/fix-homebrew-permissions-osx-el-capitan/) that might provide a route to resolving this.

I haven't tested it yet, but It appears to use `csrutil disable` temporarily to allow creation of a new directory, changing the permissions on that directory to allow "rootless" access, then re-enabling the SIP afterwards.  If nobody else does it first, I'll come back with an actual answer after I've tested it for myself.

Comment: @GrahamKlyne: thanks for the link.  It doesn't solve my problem, which was that I had software configured to live under `/usr/gnu64` and `/usr/gcc`.  I didn't have a problem with `/usr/local` except that my software wasn't using it — the directory existed OK and had acceptable permissions, and I was able to install software in it when necessary.

Comment: My thought was that you could use the procedure described to create accessible directories `/usr/gnu64` and `/usr/gcc`, then proceed as before.  But I could still be missing something.

Comment: Yes, but they'll be removed at the next upgrade, if not the next update.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that.  I was assuming that if it worked for homebrew's `/usr/local` then it could also work for other directories in `/usr`.  Oh well, it was a hopeful thought - I have a similar problem with my (recently upgraded) setup that I was hoping to resolve.

Comment: Well, I'm fairly sure one of the places I read implied if not stated that any unexpected directories in `/usr` will be moved on upgrade/update.  You're allowed `/usr/local` and sub-directories under it — that won't be a problem, even across upgrades and updates.  But other pre-existing unexpected directories under `/usr` are 'migrated' out of the way during the upgrade to El Capitan (and other upgrades, I think) and not allowed back unless you go dinking with `csrutil` on each time.  All that 'AFAIK' and 'TTBOMK', of course — and unless Apple change the rules again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106830/discussion-between-graham-klyne-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: Have you tried using the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable ? You could run your program like this: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/new/lgnu/library/path programname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of closure:

- No; there doesn't seem to be a way to avoid recompiling code.

If you want to follow the chat link, by all means do so, but it ends up at the same conclusion.

Comment: You can avoid recompilation using `install_name_tool -change` to update rpath.

Comment: For the specific example above, e.g. `install_name_tool -change /usr/gcc/v4.7.1/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib bison` should make it work (assuming you have `libgcc_s.1.dylib` in `/usr/lib`).