# Trouble downloading mlpy for Python ERROR: 'gsl/gsl_sf.h' file not found

Tags: python, terminal, gsl

I am trying to download mlpy using the instructions from the website, however I keep encoutnering the error of 'gsl/gsl_sf.h' file not found. The following code is generated, any help will be appreciated:

```
$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'mlpy/gsl/gsl.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'mlpy.gsl' extension
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c mlpy/gsl/gsl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/mlpy/gsl/gsl.o
mlpy/gsl/gsl.c:223:10: fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_sf.h' file not found
#include "gsl/gsl_sf.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

The same error being generated when using the header line:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=/path/to/header --rpath=/path/to/lib
running build_ext
skipping 'mlpy/gsl/gsl.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'mlpy.gsl' extension
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/path/to/header -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c mlpy/gsl/gsl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/mlpy/gsl/gsl.o
mlpy/gsl/gsl.c:223:10: fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_sf.h' file not found
#include "gsl/gsl_sf.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

****EDIT****

Seems like there was an issue with Xcode, after updating Xcode mlpy was imported correctly

Comment: Which OS and Python version are you using?

Comment: Ok, by the error message, you're using OSX and Python 2.7

Comment: Did you installed [GSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Scientific_Library) lib?

Comment: Yup, using OSX and 2.7. And yes I downloaded GSL using homebrew.

Comment: Maybe, brew package (GSL) does not include headers :-(

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238039/gcc-suddenly-not-finding-gsl-headers)

Comment: thank you, let me take a look.

Comment: no luck, Im still unsure which way I should be going