# OS X El Capitan Upgrade Caused Terminal to Not Work

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, upgrade, osx-elcapitan

After the El Capitan upgrade I am unable to use Terminal on my Macbook Pro. It opens up, but quickly states - [Process completed] and does not function.

I am unable to esc, control x or z to get the Terminal window to function. Does anyone know of a fix to get Terminal up and running again?

[image: terminal image attached]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  What have you got set as the shell in the terminal properties?  Could it be that the shell you were using is no longer available?  You should certainly look at the properties to see if you can work that out. Apple added SIP (System Integrity Protection) to El Capitan which means that stuff under `/usr` that isn't in `/usr/local/` has gone — if your shell was somewhere like `/usr/xyz/bin/xyzsh`, that could account for the problem. See [Mac OS X El Capitan … problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074492/) for more info.

Comment: Consider http://apple.stackexchange.com/ for questions closely related to Apple infrastructure but not specifically about programming. (StackOverflow's domain extends to "tools used *exclusively* for programming", but the terminal has other uses as well, and is as such out-of-scope).

Answer (score 1):

[image]Start in Safeboot and remove the Terminal preferences. Don't launch terminal yet. Then see if you can enter the command in terminal, but after a normal restart.

Try $ defaults write com.apple.terminal NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false

This will cause Terminal to startup cleanly. If it works after a few launches of the terminal (until you are satisfied) try the -bool true to see what happens.

Try another user account.

Go into recovery mode and enter $ resetpassword and fix ACLs.

I am not sure if any of this will work but this is what I would do.

Failing everything, I would consider a reinstall of El Cap.

I would also go to Terminal>Preferences>General and set the shell to open with the Default login shell - See attached image.