# Installing C library but Permission Denied?

Tags: c, macos, makefile, permissions

I'm trying to install this C library and I'm running:

```
sudo make  -f makefile.osx
```

but my terminal is telling me:

```
make: /usr/lib: Permission denied
```

My root user is enabled and my password is correct and everything, does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Please show what command `make` was running when that error occurred and also show the exact directory ownership and permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan and the SIP — System Integrity Protection — feature.

You can't install software in `/usr/lib` — not even if you're `root`.

You may install software under `/usr/local`, or under `/opt`.

See the discussion in [Can Mac OS X El Capitan run software compiled for Yosemite that expects libraries in `/usr/gnu64/lib`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074492/).  The short answer is "No — you can't run software that was compiled to expect libraries in a sub-directory of `/usr` that is not under `/usr/local`".  And the answer for "can I install libraries in `/usr/lib`?" is equally emphatically "No".  The question has some links to resources.